# Wordpress how to add custom post type in option page?

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

Basically, we can add custom post type in admin menu by using

> 'show_in_menu' => 'menu-slug'

but i like to know what is the code for adding this custom post type under Settings menu (option_page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its quite simple and you are nearby, just use

```
'show_in_menu' => 'options-general.php'
```